# C++ timegm conversion DST to a certain timezone at a given time in the future?

Tags: c++, time, timezone, utc, dst

I need an accurate conversion in my class from UTC time to local time of a given timezone, with or without DST in effect. My problem is, that when I use `struct tm` I have to provide the tm_isdst member, or leave it -1 to be determined automatically.

```
from mktime(3) - linux man page:
"The value specified in the tm_isdst field informs mktime() whether or not daylight saving time (DST) is in effect for the time supplied in the tm structure:
a positive value means DST is in effect;
zero means that DST is not in effect;
and a negative value means that mktime() should (use timezone information and system databases to) attempt to determine whether DST is in effect at the specified time.
```

Now here's my problem. I'm working with exchanges from all over the globe (from Chicago, New York, Sao Paolo, Melbourne, Buenos Aires, Johannesburg, Shanghai, Seoul ...). I have a table with the name of each timezone for each of the exchanges: for example Africa/Johannesburg, America/Chicago, America/Winnipeg.

The data I'm working on is expiration for some given futures and options financial instruments. The data I'm receiving is always in UTC, and I need to convert to the local time of the exchange.

Long story short, my current implementation is adding 1 extra hour to the expiration time of those assets that should not have the DST in effect (for example an instrument that expires in December and local time is America/Chicago, should add -360 minutes offset and DST 0, while another one which expires in June in the same timezone should have -360 timezone offset +60 DST offset, which would be -300 offset to the UTC timestamp. What I'm currently having the problem with, for example for the month of December I get 9:30 AM instead of 8:30 AM as the UTC timestamp contains the dst offset already.

Here is my function for doing the conversion, which is obviously broken:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define timegm _mkgmtime
#endif

SimpleDateTime BusinessDateCalculator::UTC2TZ(const SimpleDateTime& utcDateTime, const int tz_utc_offset, const int tz_dst)
{
    struct tm stm;
    memset(&stm, 0, sizeof(stm));
    stm.tm_year = utcDateTime.getYear() - 1900;
    stm.tm_mon = utcDateTime.getMonth() - 1;
    stm.tm_mday = utcDateTime.getDay();
    stm.tm_hour = utcDateTime.getHour();
    stm.tm_min = utcDateTime.getMinute();
    stm.tm_sec = utcDateTime.getSecond();
    stm.tm_isdst = -1; //see note at the top of this file

    time_t tt = timegm( &stm );
    tt += (tz_utc_offset + tz_dst) * 60;

    struct tm ntm;
    memset(&ntm, 0, sizeof(ntm));
    gmtime_r( &tt, &ntm );
    return SimpleDateTime(ntm.tm_year + 1900, ntm.tm_mon + 1, ntm.tm_mday, ntm.tm_hour, ntm.tm_min, ntm.tm_sec, utcDateTime.getMillisecond());
}
```

Where SimpleDateTime is a date-time class with additional functionality, like conversion from different date/time formats (SQL, FIX, Timeonly, DateOnly).

I have the timezone information of a certain exchange available at all time. My question can I provide the timezone name somehow, and let the `timegm` perform a database search and determine whether in the America/Chicago timezone the DST is or is not in effect on 2014-12-19 and accordingly not add the extra 60 minutes to the UTC time, and on the same date for example in the southern hemisphere timezone America/Sao_Paulo it is in effect until 16 Feb 2015, and for this timestamp it should add 60 minutes to get the correct local time for the given date.

Comment: I don't see a clear question here. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I want to know how I can transform 2014-12-19 11:50:00.123 UTC time into a certain timezones local time: for example America/Chicago timezone, and get the correct time without having to worry about DST, because when I transform to America/Sao_Paulo, the DST will be in effect in that timezone.

Comment: I'm happy with any solution (not necessarily timegm), as the date and time has to be 100% accurate. If for example boost could do this, I'm happy with that solution either, as I'm already using some boost shared pointers and static cast in my program. What I was trying to say I don't have the DST information available... but I have to keep in mind that some timezones at certain dates have the DST in effect, while others don't. I always have the timezone offset and official timezone name available, but not the DST offset, which can either be 0 or 60 for a given tz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refer to a time zone by it's IANA identifier (eg `"America/Chicago"`) - that already includes all of the DST information and full history of the time zone.  At least, it does in the original source data in [the IANA time zone database](http://iana.org/time-zones).

You mentioned [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) (in comments).  While Boost does have support for these types of identifiers, it makes the mistake of assuming that they are permanently fixed in time.  That is not true, as time zones of the world change their offsets and DST rules all the time.  Consider that the USA changed its DST rules in 2007, and that Russia is changing its time zones significantly later this year (Oct. 2014).   If you look at the [Boost time zone data file](https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/blob/master/data/date_time_zonespec.csv), you'll see that its format strips away all of the history and just maps each identifier to a single set of rules.   For this reason, I recommend you do *not* use Boost for local time zone conversions.

Instead, consider using [ICU](http://icu-project.org/).  Among other things, it includes time zone conversion functions, and uses the full copy of the IANA time zone database.  [You can read more here,](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/timezone) and see [sample code here.](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/timezone/examples)  I'm not particularly skilled in C++, but it would appear that you can use ICU's `Calendar` class to project a UTC time to a local time in a particular time zone.

Another option would be to use the time zone functions built in to [the GNU C library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/documentation.html).  It also uses the full time zone database.  There's a simple example of converting UTC tor local time using an IANA/Olson identifier [on this site](http://rl.se/convert-utc-to-local-time), which I have also posted below:

```
/*
    C source code example: Convert UTC to local time zone, considering daylight
    savings. Uses mktime(), gmtime() and localtime(). Works for dates between
    years 1902 and 2037. Should compile and run with any recent GNU C if your
    tzdata is healthy. Written by Robert Larsson  http://rl.se

    Code put in public domain; do what you want with it.
*/

#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <time.h>

#define     DESTZONE    "TZ=Europe/Stockholm"       // Our destination time zone

int main(void)
{
    struct tm   i;
    time_t      stamp;                              // Can be negative, so works before 1970

    putenv("TZ=UTC");                               // Begin work in Greenwich …

    i.tm_year = 2009-1900;                          // Populate struct members with
    i.tm_mon  = 8-1;                                // the UTC time details, we use
    i.tm_mday = 29;                                 // 29th August, 2009 12:34:56
    i.tm_hour = 12;                                 // in this example
    i.tm_min  = 34;
    i.tm_sec  = 56;

    stamp = mktime(&i);                             // Convert the struct to a Unix timestamp

    putenv(DESTZONE);                               // Switch to destination time zone

    printf("UTC  : %s", asctime(gmtime(&stamp)));
    printf("Local: %s", asctime(localtime(&stamp)));

    return 0;                                       // That’s it, folks.
}
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, GNU C and setting the environment variable to IANA code works great for me. It's quite simple, but very effective. i verified. I'm satisfied with the result.

Comment: OK, There's a serious flaw in this implementation. It works well in single-threaded programs, but it leads to random seg faults in multi-threaded programs. If 2 concurrent threads are modifying the variable can lead to undesired behavior. After you call the second putenv, it's possible that another thread is already modifying your variable to putenv("TZ=UTC"); of course this meanse that your local and gmt times are incorrect. It happened to me yesterday that my app crashed with segmentation fault. I investigated and this is the reason. SO BEWARE! only use this implementation in single threaded

Comment: A mutex cannot help either since environment variables are shared between threads, you can only put a mutex for putenv, which is thread safe by default (according to documentation). I'm looking for an alternative implementation, since this doesn't seem to work for me. I read that I could set up signals which would suspend other threads while doing the conversion, and emit a resume signal after the conversion is done. This would lead to delays of course...

Comment: I've seen this can have possible side effects (I know it's not thread safe), but on the lung run, I saw this can lead to changing the timezone for the whole application (mostly visible in log files, when another thread is logging while the putenv variable is set, the logging time and date is off - it's set to destzone). I'm now orienting to Google's CCTZ library which uses std::chrono for conversions.