# Getting OFFSET while Converting UTC time to specific time zone in c++

Tags: c++, time.h

I am trying to get the time as per the time zone.
the offset value for India is 5:30 so I am adding 5 hours and 30 mins to the time obtained using "time" function.
But the final answer always gives 1 hour offset. Why ? how should I correct it ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>


int main() {

        time_t tNow;
        time(&tNow); 

        struct tm *now = localtime(&tNow);

        cout<<asctime(now)<<endl;

     // for Indian time (GMT 5:30) adding 5 to hour and 30 to min

        cout<< (now->tm_hour +5)%24 <<" "<< (now->tm_min +30)%60 <<" "<< now->tm_sec +0<< endl;


}
```

What changes should I do to correct this ?

Comment: Could you please paste the output?

Comment: @Upasana his output would be errors because cout<< will give the "error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope" and didn't add using namespace std;

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ timegm conversion DST to a certain timezone at a given time in the future?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170287/c-timegm-conversion-dst-to-a-certain-timezone-at-a-given-time-in-the-future)

Comment: @Bot I am assuming, she did "using namespace std;" in her original program, but missed it here!

Comment: The output: Sun Jan 11 14:28:00 2015
Timezone Time:19:58:0 There is no problem

Comment: Mon Jan 12 04:56:09 2015                                             
timezone time                                        
9:26:9
this is the output. actually the output should have been 10:26:9

Comment: Hi the problem is i was compiling the code using online compiler, and thus was not matching with my local time.