# Conversion of times in C++

Tags: c++, time

This is what I am trying to do:

1. Get the local time (from the system);
2. Convert that time to the UTC format and associate it with some member variable of current object.
3. Later on, given the timezone of the user, I wish to convert it into the correct local time and display it to the user.

Looking up few things on SO and CppReference, I could come up with the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    time_t lt = std::time(0);
    //time(0) gives current time, but LTime shows the UTC time (not local time)
    string LTime = std::ctime(&lt); //localtime() gives error
    cout<<LTime;

    //timestamp = mktime(&tm) - timezone;
    //time_t timestamp = mktime(&tm) - _timezone;
    //std::cout << "timestamp: " << std::put_time(timestamp, "%c %Z") << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

1. The example on cppreference.com illustrates how the value can be printed using `put_time()`; but how to store it in a variable?
2. How to convert the UTC time format to current timezone (given some timezone as the input)?  I tried using the commented code above as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5157134/2172854) but it does not take any parameter.

Comment: consider C++'s chrono library.

Comment: @Charles, can we work with timezones using that?  How do we go about changing the timezones in it?

Comment: Here's something called [std::localtime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime)

Comment: And there's this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170287/c-timegm-conversion-dst-to-a-certain-timezone-at-a-given-time-in-the-future

Comment: @Charles, yes.  If you notice, my code is very similar to that.  However, they are using `put_time()` to display the time; I wanna store the time in some format and later convert this into a date format again (taking into account the time zone).

Comment: Why _store_ as a string?

Comment: @Charles, sorry, any format would work.  I edited my earlier comment.  Apologies.

Comment: If you're interested, here is a library that will do this without setting a global like `TZ`: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local time get the local time and gmt time for UTC
You can set the Time zone using the list [Time zone wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
    std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
    auto local = std::asctime(std::localtime(&result));
    std::cout <<local;
    std::cout << "UTC:   " << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&result), "%c %Z") << '\n';
    putenv("TZ=Asia/Singapore");
    local = std::asctime(std::localtime(&result));
    std::cout <<"Asia/Singapore Time "<<local;

}
```

Output

```
Thu Sep 14 21:59:37 2017
UTC:   Fri Sep 15 01:59:37 2017 UTC
Asia/Singapore Time Fri Sep 15 09:59:37 2017
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Thank you.  And then how to convert the UTC time to local time, dynamically (like say, with the timezone passed as one of the parameters)?

Comment: I think OP wants more control over timezones

Comment: @Charles, yes, using something like `TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Copenhagen");` in Java to convert to target timezone.

Comment: Are you ok to use any library like tz?

Comment: @HariomSingh, yes, I can use that.

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela   I was just confused with moment.js .I used long ago for timezone ..But finally some wiki helped to get the answer

Comment: @HariomSingh, thank you, that works like a charm.  One qq though - when I run the code on Ideone.com, the local time printed is the same as the UTC time.  Do you think it is so because the ideone server is in that time zone?